# Tiny wi-fi module on one board with ALU and memory?

Tags: wifi, cpu, board, network-interface

I am looking for small and cheap wi-fi modules and I want to know, what are the current best results in this area. Also, I would like to know, if it is possible to seamlessly integrate such modules on one board with ALU and memory (to make it sort of "fundamental" thing, playing vital role in small device's functioning).

Sorry for kind of stupid question and thanks for your answers!

Comment: If you want even smaller and cheaper wireless modules, but don't necessarily require WiFi, you might want to look at [wireless sensor nodes](http://wsn.oversigma.com/).

Answer (score 1):

[Microchip](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2885&param=en547232) do some pretty good WiFi modules. Combined with a PIC32, (which has an ALU and memory) you can create a pretty fundamental thing. MIcrochip also provide a free TCP stack which you can use in your firmware.

[image: Microchip WiFi Module]